# How to trigger function from javascript websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am new to websocket. I am currently listening to a websocket in my node.js middleware application. Once I receive a message I have to store that message on database.

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");

ws.on("message", (event) => {
  console.log("connected to DB");
  testConnection();
});
```

Whenever a new message is received the `testConnection` function should be triggered.

```
async function testConnection() {
  await sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to DB");
   })
   .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

I am trying to test connection for now.

But whenever a new message is received the `testConnection` function is not getting called.

I would like to know how to call a function when receiving a new message.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the Websockets [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) the message handlers is a callback on the websocket `onmessage` calling `on` will just return undefined.

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");

ws.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log("connected to DB");
  testConnection();
};


async function testConnection() {
  await sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to DB");
   })
   .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: whenever a message is sent the `ws.onmessage` function is not getting invoked. I tried with breakpoints in my node service.

Comment: @TonyRoczz could you add your node websocket code into the question?

Comment: Its working now. it was some other error with my code.

Comment: @TonyRoczz amazing! Could you mark this as the correct answer?